# TFS : How do you control signoff of test cases

Tags: testing, tfs, mtm

We are newbies to TFS **(2015)**  and one of the things we have noticed is the fact that you can mark an overall **Test Case** as "passed" without giving a reason or having any specific authority to do so.

This presents an issues for us, as you can mark a **Test Case** as "passed" even when: 
 - Test steps have failed
 - Bugs have not been fixed
 - Test case have only partially been completed
 - No test steps have been run

What we really want to do is perform a supervisor review of the **Test Case**. We do this currently to check:
 - all bugs are addressed any marked as "fixed later" have a comments explaining
 - test evidence has been stored correctly
 - variance form test plan recorded as comment

We get audited on regular basis and supervisor review helps a lot, as an audit can can be on projects 2-4 years old, checking, recording decisions and reasons at the at the time of signing of test  off , just helps.

**Question**: Is there a way of controlling sign-off of a **Test Case** or **Test Suite**?

Forcing a comment to be entered or restricting access to marking **Test Case** as "passed" would be something

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you testing the test case in TFS web portal or in MTM?

Comment: We are using latest version TFS 2015 update 2 (On Premise)  .We are also considering upgrading to 2017.

 
We have not decided whether to get testers to use Web but expect them to use MTM.

    If it makes a difference then we will certainly consider 
    forcing them to use one method or another

Answer (score 1):

There is no (out of the box) way to explicitly control who can mark a test case as passed. Usually you would be able to configure such transitions using the Work Item Type Definition (WITD) by adding rules and constraints to a transitions. But since test results are not represented as work items this is not possible.

You can restrict access on a higher level, on test plans and test suites:
[image]

There might be a way to get it the way you want it using the TFS Server Object Model and building a server side validation, not sure if this is possible since I have never tried this (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.120).aspx#ServerObjectModel). I would however try to avoid building a server side validation since it is on you to make sure it keeps working and might cause issues or blocking issues in a future upgrade for you. It would be a pity to get stuck on a version of TFS because of this.

Hope this helps!